# Error adding Nuget packages in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package

I am new to Windows Universal development and am trying to add the restsharp using visual studio nugget package manager but whenever I click on install, I get this error:

> The process cannot access the file 'System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll' because it is being used by another process.

I have started Visual Studio as administrator and yet this didn't solve my issue.

I have also tried clearing Nuget cache via

```
 debug->options->nugget manager->clear
```

but also this doesn't solve it.

How do I solve this to enable add on nuget packages to my project?

Comment: You might need to restart your computer then try installing the package

Comment: Ive tried restarting and still behaves this way, i have resulted to downloading dlls from the github repository and added a reference to them in my project

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce your error, what version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: am using visual studio community bedition latest version 2017

Answer (score 0):

Tried this method? Adding Reference in VS is complicating

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-ui